# API to render word document with Merge fields

Tags: mail-merge

I was trying to render the word documents attached to the Mail Merge Templates with Merge fields in the code(Apex class). I was hoping Salesforce would be having some API similar to Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate() for Email templates. But unfortunately i could not find any.

I am trying to avoid using Mail Merge & Extended Mail merge just because they have lot of browser compatibility issues and they are currently not supported in lightning. I don't even want to go for any 3rd party tools like Conga.

I am basically trying to implement Mailing & bulk Mailing features in Salesforce on my own. Can someone help me in this regard?

Comment: Are you fixated on Word, or would you accept a PDF?

Comment: @sfdcfox I am ok with rendering it in PDF also.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this, Anee? This [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br13AAC) makes it sound like Salesforce broke its "API-first" approach to features on this one

Comment: @BrentBow, Unfortunately no. We are thinking of going for 'Conga' for handling our mailing needs.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, Anee. Really wish this were a feature. You can [upvote the SF Idea here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br13).